# python variables as class

Tags: python, watson

im following the ibm watson documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/python.html?python#create-a-classifier

in the example:

```
model = visual_recognition.create_classifier(
        'dogs',
        beagle_positive_examples=beagle,
```

i wanna substitute the beagles with the content of a variable, like

```
    var1=XXX
    model = visual_recognition.create_classifier(
        'dogs',
        var1_positive_examples=beagle,
```

is it possible? how?

thanks in advance i hope is not a stupid question.

Comment: take a look at **kwargs syntax, which let you pass arbitrary arguments as key-value pairs in a dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
var1 = 'beagle'
params = {'{}_positive_examples'.format(var1): beagle}
model = visual_recognition.create_classifier('dogs', **params)
```